# tell php to create a new object at certain moments in time, Cronjobs?

Tags: php, cron

I’m trying to create this application but my current knowledge prevents me from building it, hope that you can help me!

**Scenario**

I’m creating some sort of dairy application. From the moment the user presses the start button an object is created, which the user can later edit by filling in his report.

Now the user is only allowed to write one report every day, so a new object has to be added to the database at 0:00 am, which then again he can fill in.

**Question**

How can I tell php to create a new object at certain moments in time?

I was thinking of doing it like this:

1. A page that only shows when no objects are created so far. A new object is created when the button “Start journey is pressed”.
2. A page that adds an object when the time is 0:00 (*using cronjobs?)
3. A page that displays all the created days and allows the user to edit them.

*So far the only solution that I’ve found is to use cronjobs, but I’m not familiar with these. Are cronjobs the right way to go for me and how can I use them (I’m testing my code on MAMP)? Or is it possible to get there solely with php, and how?

All help is much appreciated!
lvRoy

Comment: Just a question : why do you want your object to be created no matter what at 00:00 and to be filled later ? Is it necessary it to be generated at midnight ?

Comment: I'm thinking of a dairy application that generates 1 report a day, assuming that the user is dedicated enough to use this app every day. So an empty object is created every day which the user can fill in later. Of course I'm willing to change this plan, but this is the way I see it right now.

Comment: Could it be possible (with your restriction) to generate this object only at the daily first use ? When the user access his panel, it would check there is already a object (or not) for this day and if not then it would create this object ?

Comment: Yes absolutely, I just can't imagine how exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could it be possible (with your restriction) to generate this object only at the daily first use ? When the user access his panel, it would check there is already a object (or not) for this day and if not then it would create this object ?

If this would be okay for you, then you could do something like this :

First, you could add another property for the user (in database/session) named "next_check" which would represent the next time (date or timestamp) you would need to check if the object has been created.

At runtime, you would check if this property is lower than the current time, e.g :

```
if ($user['next_check'] <= time()) {
   //create task
}
```

If you need to create this task (condition is true), then you would create your object and update "next_check" value to time(). Else, you do not do anything.

Notice that this solution would lose history of your objects since, if the user does not access this app for 10 days, there would not be any objects created for 10 days but just 1 when he finally logs on your app.

You could of course improve this to generate an object per day even if the user does not access your app by iterating on the conditions while "next_check" is lower than time().

```
while ($user['next_check'] <= time()) {
   //create object
   $user['next_check'] += 3600 * 24;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need cronjobs at all (if I understood this correctly). You just check on creation of a new report whether or not they already created a report that day. If the answer is no you can create a new item in the database with the correct data, otherwise you return an error with the message "already created a report for this day".

Comment: This would indeed solve my problem, I just had no idea that this was possible to check the database on whether or not something was created the past 'x hours'?

Comment: You create a query that looks a bit like this `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sometable WHERE date(date_column) = '2015-05-05';` and use the result to store or otherwise reject the action